# install nginx on suse linux enterprise 11

Tags: nginx, opensuse, sles

I need some help getting ngnix installed on Suse Linux Enterprise 11. This is my first time trying to do this so I am likely missing something basic. Thus far I have:

`wget http://nginx.org/packages/opensuse/12.1/SRPMS/nginx-1.4.7-1opensuse12.1.ngx.src.rpm`

the under sudo I ran

`yast nginx-1.4.7-1opensuse12.1.ngx.src.rpm`

This installed several files under /usr/src/packages/SOURCES/

but, for example, when I run `chkconfig --add ngnix` I get an `ngnix: unknown service` error.

What steps did I miss during the install

(I was able to get this all up and running on the regular version of Suse Linux 13.1 but the differences between that and Enterprise are confusing me...)

Answer (score 2):

You've installed the source package rather than the compiled version.

Instead, try

```
http://nginx.org/packages/opensuse/12.1/x86_64/RPMS/nginx-debug-1.4.7-1opensuse12.1.ngx.x86_64.rpm`
```

or, for a 32-bit install,

```
http://nginx.org/packages/opensuse/12.1/i586/RPMS/nginx-debug-1.4.7-1opensuse12.1.ngx.i586.rpm
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I'm giving it a try now but running into so many dependency issues...

Answer (score 0):

nginx.org currently provide binaries for opensuse 12.1 and sles 12

The instructions [here](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) are for SLES 12, but here they are repeated and modified for opensuse 12.1

```
sudo zypper addrepo -G -t yum -c 'http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/opensuse/12.1' nginx
sudo zypper in nginx
```

Or you can add opensuse build binaries.
**But** in your question you ask about *SLES 11*, but I saw that you were installing *opensuse12.1* src packages.  This is a cause of your problem, you cannot do this, or if you can it's the wrong way *SLES != opensuse*, but also if you are using open use, you'd prefer opensuse 11 for SLES 11.

Goto to

https://software.opensuse.org/package/nginx

Click on the version of SLES 11 you are using, if it's SP4 then the main repo 'server:http' is not configured.  If you are on SP3 then clicking on https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?project=server%3Ahttp&package=nginx shows that even though SP3 is configured it isn't currently building as GeoIP is unresolved.

But you want the legacy version of nginx 1.4.7, rather than the current stable 1.8.0

You can look through the [builds](https://software.opensuse.org/package/nginx) and see if you can find a matching SLES 11 SPx and nginx version you want.

Then I would add it as a repo, here's how I added nginx to SLES 12 (note `osb_suse_servers_http` is just the name I use for the repo)

```
sudo zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/http/SLE_12 osb_suse_servers_http
sudo zypper in nginx
```